# Unexpected behavior when tracing index array in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I'm running into some unexpected behavior using a while loop to get index quantities related to tracing quantities from one array to another.

My input code is:

```
from numpy import array
from numpy.ma import where as mwhere
from numpy.ma import masked_array, masked
start_pts = array([False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True])
active    = array([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True])
spline_index = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
pt0     = array([1, 0, 3, 0, 6, 4, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0])
m_a_pt0 = masked_array(pt0, start_pts)

for i in range(3):
    # start pt
    pt = mwhere((spline_index[active] == i) & (start_pts[active] == 1))
    print pt
    while pt[0]:
        pt = mwhere((spline_index[active] == i) & (m_a_pt0[active] == pt[0]))
        print i, pt
```

I am expecting an output of:

```
(array([1]),)
0 (array([0]),)
0 (array([3]),)
0 (array([2]),)
0 (array([], dtype=int64,)
(array([6]),)
1 (array([4]),)
1 (array([5]),)
1 (array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([10]),)
2 (array([9]),)
2 (array([8]),)
2 (array([7]),)
2 (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

But instead the while loop exits when pt = array([0],) and I get:

```
(array([1]),)
0 (array([0]),)
(array([6]),)
1 (array([4]),)
1 (array([5]),)
1 (array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([10]),)
2 (array([9]),)
2 (array([8]),)
2 (array([7]),)
2 (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

But if I test a value where:

```
test = (array([0]),)
print mwhere((spline_index[active] == 0) & (m_a_pt0[active] == test[0]))
```

This returns the expected tuple with array:

```
(array([3]),)
```

Why is my while loop prematurely exiting for array([0]), when values still exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy arrays with length one have the truth value of their single element.  See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043901/truth-value-of-numpy-array-with-one-falsey-element-seems-to-depend-on-dtype).  If you want to check if the array is empty, check if its length is zero.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do a more "pythonic" check as seen [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Pythonic-way-to-check-for-an-empty-set), but missed that it is not valid for arrays.